# Define a text to later insert multiple timesr

Tags: cross-referencing

is there any possibility to define a text which I can then input multiple times later?

My problem: I'm writing on a thesis and want to define the titel of it, so I can later reference this titel. So if the name or some words in the titel change (which might happen) I don't have to go through the whole thesis and change it all the times I used the titel.

I know this sounds pretty weird, my english is also not quite good. I hope I could explain what I ment to you to an extend where someone understands ^^

Comment: `\newcommand{\MyTitle}{Awesome Stuff}`, then use `\MyTitle`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that worked, awesome! If I knew how i'd close the thread as solved :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.

Comment: @Zarko Would be better I think to either close as duplicate of something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176390/ (that one's for math mode, but otherwise same principle) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73637/.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., the question seems to be duplicate to the question on the second link. i will try to change my proposition for closing of the question.